# Add external type serialization to msgpack

Tags: c++, msgpack

How can I add an external type (a complex type in a third-party library for example) to msgpack serialization?

I have a class `foo` which has a member of type `bar` implemented in `libbar.so` and I want to serialize `foo` such that it includes its `bar`. In case it matters, `bar` can be converted to a trivial type (say int) and be constructed from that type back into `bar`.

Example:

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <bar.hpp>
class foo {
public:
  int a;
  double b;
  bar z;
  MSGPACK_DEFINE(a,b,z)
}
```

bar.hpp:

```
class bar {
public:
    // ...
    void set_from_known_type(int x);
    int  export_to_known_type() const;
private:
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you can write adaptor class template specialization to serialize `bar`.

Comment: @wangke1020 Seems only available for version 1 and higher. I'm using debian 7 default version (0.5.7)